# Function keys work when I press fn key together with them

Tags: function-keys

My F keys (f1, f3, f4 etc.) are not working properly - meaning that I have to press fn+f1 for example for f1 to work. Now when I press just f1 I get audio muted because that is what is supposed to do when pressed fn+f1. How to reverse this thing? So that when I press f2 for example on a file it would enable rename function, because in order to do that now I have to press fn+f2

ubuntu 20.04
DE - KDE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look carefully at your keyboard - there is probably a "Fn lock" function. On mine there is a little padlock symbol on the ESC key, and Fn+ESC toggles Fn lock on/off. But if on a laptop think about keys like Ins, Del, Home, End as they might be on a Fn function if you toggle Fn lock.

Comment: sometimes this can also be done from BIOS, when the pad lock option is not there

Comment: Thanks that indeed helped! Padlock symbol is on Esc, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I has been install kubuntu 22.04 with external keyboard Edra EK361W, When I rename file (Fn + 2 => F2) my os going to change light of keyboard -_-.
So, I boot into windows by usb and install Driver of Edra keyboard and restart into Kubuntu and it's worked, I don't know why. Now when pressing Fn + 2 it will do behavior like F2 button on full keyboard.
[image]